# How to access an element's class value via CSS

Tags: css

How can I access the numbers (1 and 2 in the example below) at the end of the paragraph's class string via CSS?

`<p class="cooking-step-1">

    <!-- Second step ... -->

</p>`

`<p class="cooking-step-2">

    <!-- Second step ... -->

</p>`

I can access these paragraphs via the following selector: `p[class^="cooking-step-"]`
I want to add the paragraph's number in front of the text inside of it via the CSS `content` property. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without the help of jQuery. Also, your selector is relatively new and will fail in some browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible using [counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters). However, browser support is spotty and I think the spec changed for CSS3.

Basically, you do not even need the `cooking-step-N` class. If you use a class like `cooking-step`, you can simply let the engine do the counting for you. Increment it on each `.cooking-step` and use its `counter()` for the `content`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with set steps and trying to number them, then you should probably try to use an ordered list instead.  The `ol` indicates that the items belong in the given order, and it provides numbering without any extra work!

If you really want to use CSS, then counters are what you're looking for.  In the containing element for these paragraphs, apply the style `counter-reset: step`.  Then for your paragraph tags use:

```
p:before {   
    counter-increment: step;   
    content: counter(step)". ";   
}
```

This should work in modern browsers, but because of simplicity and legacy browser support, I think you'll be happier with just an ordered list.